# Best way (logic) to model an XOR?

Tags: digital-logic

Some people say that the best way to model an XOR is to use NMOS pass logic. Others say its better to use a transmission gate (or simply, pass logic). The only difference I could find in these implementations was the number of transistors required and that won't matter too much in a simple design with, say, five XORs. However, I maybe wrong and there may be some other parameters that have to be maintained when modelling an XOR. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "one best way", there are only requirements (explicit and inferred) and designs that do or do not meet those requirements.

Among the many requirements are:

- # of transistors in the cell
- the fan-in (how much of a load does each cell present to the the source)
- the fan-out (how much of load can each cell drive)
- the propagation delay
- symmetry of propagation delay (+'ve vs. -'ve edge) or assymmetry for that matter
- power consumption
- shoot through current when switching
- metal layers used in fabrication
- any more that I can't think of right now.

THe pass gate and TG versions mentioned have very low transistor counts and very poor driving (fan-out) to name some of their attributes.

To answer your question explicitly, the best way to model a XOR gate is to model what was actually built or how you intend to build it.